# Joining 4 tables together in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join a main table to 2 other tables in mysqli and not getting the results I expect.

Tables:

MAIN

[image]

USERS

[image]

AP_STORES

[image]

APPROVALS

[image]

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT *
    FROM main
    LEFT OUTER JOIN users ON
            main.uid = users.uid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ap_stores ON
            main.ap_id = ap_stores.ap_id"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN approvals ON
            main.job_no = approvals.job_no
```

Output:

```
Array (

[JOB_NO] => 
[UID] => 
[AP_ID] => 
[FILES] => Doc1_testy.pdf
[UPLOAD_COMMENTS] => test
[ENTRY_DATE] => 2015-11-28 14:33:18
[FIRST_NAME] => john
[LAST_NAME] => smith
[USERNAME] => jsmith
[PASSWORD] => ######
[USER_TYPE] => admin
[EMAIL] => jsmith@something,com
[APPROVER_TYPE] => slo
[NAME] => 
[BRAND_DATE] => 
[SLO_DATE] => 
[AP_DATE] => 
)
```

> What I am trying to achieve:
>
> 1. ALL rows in main
> 2. Row in users where main.uid = users.uid
> 3. Row in ap_stores where main.ap_id = ap_stores.ap_id
> 4. Row in approvals where main.job_no = approvals.job_no

There will always be a matching record in the users table.

There will always be a matching record in the ap_stores table.

Sometimes there will be no match in the approvals table.

Everything seems to return ok, except the first 3 fields, which are also the fields that I am using to join the tables. They should not be empty.

Comment: please post table definition, sample input and desired output

Comment: Also please post the *actual* output from this query, along with any error messages you see.